# Siebel open UI IP16 - loading image customization

Tags: oracle, user-interface, siebel

Is there a way I can customize (replace with another GIF image) the loading image in Siebel Open UI in IP16 version? The current loading image is an red colored, oval shaped, oracle provided one, but i do not find the corresponding image in images folder. Any leads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animated icon may be stored in css files.

Try to search in your css files for something like

- .siebui-mask-outer
- timer

It may not be an actual gif but an css transformation.

(btw. You can run your Chrome Developer tool and examine the source of the icon)

Comment: you are correct. Its an css animation and I was able to customize it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The standard GIF file must be in public/enu folder (for english application) on the web server. On your local installation, it will be in C:\Siebel81\16.0.0.0.0\Client\PUBLIC\IMAGES\

There are multiple gif files there used for different applications.

Comment: I could see the similar favicon in the IMAGES folder but not the spinner one used in loading. Even I double checked the IMAGES folder before posting the question here.

Comment: I moved all the files from IMAGES folder and verified. Still the loading icon is showing up (but not other images) when application is loaded, Not sure, from where this is been brought up